# Error messages with different situations while saving to database with php form

Tags: php, mysql

i have a script that saves records to mysql with no problem. but i want to add some code to show an error message if the name or code already exists in the database. the code is like below;

```
<?php

$urunadi        = $_POST["urunadi"];
$malzemekodu    = $_POST["malzemekodu"];
$urunkategorisi = $_POST["urunkategorisi"];
$birim          = $_POST["birim"];
$miktar         = $_POST["miktar"];
$personel       = $_POST["personel"];
$birimfiyat     = $_POST["birimfiyat"];
$toplamfiyat    = $_POST["birimfiyat"]*$_POST["miktar"];
$fiyatbirimi    = $_POST["fiyatbirimi"];


if(empty($urunadi)){
echo("<center><b>Product name empty, please go back and fill this line.</b></center>");
}else
if(empty($miktar)){
echo("<center><b>Product amount empty, please go back and fill this line.
}else
if(empty($malzemekodu)){
echo("<center><b>Product code empty, please go back and fill this line.</b></center>");
}else
if(empty($birimfiyat)){
echo("<center><b>Unit price empty, please go back and fill this line.</b></center>");
}else{
include "database.php";
$sql = (" insert into `depo` (`urunadi`,`malzemekodu`,`urunkategorisi`,`birim`,`miktar`,`personel`,`birimfiyat`,`toplamfiyat`,`fiyatbirimi`)
VALUES ('$urunadi','$malzemekodu','$urunkategorisi','$birim','$miktar','$personel','$birimfiyat','$toplamfiyat','$fiyatbirimi');");
$kayit = mysql_query($sql);
}
if (isset ($kayit)){
echo "<center>Data saved</center>";
}
else {
echo "<center>Data could not be saved</center>";
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["kullanici"])) {
include("database.php");
$sql = ("select * from uye");
}
else {
header ("Location: uyari.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: You've lost some quotes. Have a look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with above code, i want add some codes to show "same record" error and not to save them to database.

Comment: Those fields should have an unique index. The query will fail and you can handle the error according to your needs.

Comment: i am really a beginner so there is a lack of information. those fields are already unique but it says "data saved" after a data entered which is in the db but not saved.

Comment: [mysql_query](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns false on error. You should test with `if ($kayit !== false)` instead of `isset($kayit)` because [isset](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns `true`, if the variable `$kayit` has the value `false`: the variable is set and not `Null`.